# Player not showing and converting to "Download File" "mediaelement.js"

Tags: mediaelement.js

I have uploaded my most recent audio to our churches website. When visiting the page the audio player will show for a brief second then switch to "Download File".

If you click download file the player will show again for a brief second.

All of my previous uploads still function correctly.

I am running Wordpress 3.8.1